# Feature stapling always returns item does not exist: it may have been deleted by another user

Tags: 2013, development, custom-masterpage, feature-receiver, feature-stapling

I'm attempting to create a feature stapled solution that pushes out custom branding to every new site collection created. The following code is in my event receiver:

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using(SPSite sitecollection = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
        {
            using (SPWeb site = sitecollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in sitecollection.AllWebs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Composed Looks");
                        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                        {
                            if(item.Title != "Current" || item.Title != "Dynetics")
                            {
                                item.Delete();
                                item.Update();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if(web != null)
                        {
                            web.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when deploying the solution I get the error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

WHY??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into your code, i think the problem is

```
item.Delete();
item.Update();
```

You are updating item after you are deleting, there is no need to update the item after delete.

You can not update a deleted item.

Comment: Ok that got rid of the original error, but now I receive: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: use for (int i = items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    SPListItem item = items[i];
    item.Delete();
   }

Comment: you are getting this error because You can not modify a collection while enumerating it because the iterator will reset and you will have exception.I

Comment: Or you can maintain a list of listitems to delete and delete them one by one after your foreach statement.

Comment: Tremendously helpful, Aanchal. Thank you very much. This solved the problem

Comment: Please mark this as answer , if it solves your problem.

Comment: Just did...please consider ranking my question up as well :)